# CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.rtBox'

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a method in primary class WriteIt(string text) which communicates with RichTextBox rtBox which is already in GUI.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public static void WriteIt(string text)
        {
            rtBox.Text = text + "/n" + rtBox.Text;
        }
    }
```

I want to call this method from other class like this:

```
class Register
{
        public int balance = 0;
        public static void ListIt()
        {
            Form1.WriteIt("Money: " + balance);
        }
}
```

It gives me an Error:

> CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field,
> method, or property 'Form1.rtBox'

Due to nature of the program I cant make ListIt() become a non-static method. I tried some similar solutions that I saw here but they didnt work for me. What should I do?

Comment: "Due to nature of the program I cant make ListIt() become a non-static method." Well then what do you expect to happen if there are multiple instances of Form1? Which one would you expect to end up changing text box? Fundamentally, *something* needs to have a reference to an instance of Form1 in order to change the text on *that specific form*.

Comment: You need to use the object of `Form1` in the `ListIt` method

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling a non static member (a property or method, or more specifically Form1.rtBox) from a static method. You have a couple of options:

1. Make the called member static also:
2. Create an instance of rtBox within the calling method
3. Make the calling method a non-static instance method